# data table looping just check first row and not continue to next row c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have 2 rows in data table, first contain "P" and "B", the second just contain "P", but this looping just check the first row

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Personel where Kode_Personel LIKE '%P%' ", con);
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
con.Open();
sda.Fill(dt);
con.Close();

int j = 0;
 foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
 {

     j++;
     cekjabatan = dt.Rows[0].ItemArray[2].ToString(); //this value not change to next row
     cekkode = dt.Rows[0].ItemArray[0].ToString(); //this value not change to next row

     if (cekkode.Contains("A") && cekkode.Contains("P") || cekkode.Contains("B") && cekkode.Contains("P") || cekkode.Contains("C") && cekkode.Contains("P"))
     {
        ceksubstring = cekkode.Substring(0, 4);
     }
     else if (cekkode.Contains("P") && !cekkode.Contains("B"))
     {
        ceksubstring = cekkode.Substring(0, 3);
     }
 }
```

Comment: You are using `dt.Rows[0]` which means the first row. You may want to use `row` (the loop variable).

Comment: hehe my bad, thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
cekjabatan = dt.Rows[0].ItemArray[2].ToString(); //this value not change to next row
```

because you access always the same position at each iteration.

You can either use the variable `j` that you instantiated as the iterator

```
cekjabatan = dt.Rows[j].ItemArray[2].ToString();
```

but beware to increment it after all assingments (as the last statement inside the for-loop block), or you will loose the first element.

But this solution makes the iterator variable `row` obsolete. You should use the loop variable as it is intended:

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{

    cekjabatan = row.ItemArray[2].ToString(); //this value not change to next row
    cekkode = row.ItemArray[0].ToString(); //this value not change to next row

    if (cekkode.Contains("A") && cekkode.Contains("P") || cekkode.Contains("B") && cekkode.Contains("P") || cekkode.Contains("C") && cekkode.Contains("P"))
    {
        ceksubstring = cekkode.Substring(0, 4);
    }
    else if (cekkode.Contains("P") && !cekkode.Contains("B"))
    {
        ceksubstring = cekkode.Substring(0, 3);
    }
 }
```

In this case you can remove `int j` entirely